# Hibernate Create Criteria

Tags: hibernate, search, grails, groovy

So im trying to make a search function. Im using Hibernates Create Criteria to try to get it done. Im searching by 2 values. If one of the values is null then it will throw an exception, if not it will continue to show all the information regarding that search in a table.

```
    def search(params) {

def r = User.createCriteria()

if (params.searchUsername != 'Enter a Username' && params.searchMPI != 'Enter a User Number') {
    def number = params.searchNumber
    def username = params.searchUsername

    r = User.createCriteria()


    def userList = r.list(max: params.max, offset: params.usersOffset) {
        and {
            ilike('username', '%' + username + '%')
            ilike('number', '%' + number + '%')
        }
        order(params.usersSort, params.usersOrder)
    }
}
```

This is my search function thus far. It searches for a username and a user number. Pretty much there HAS to be a username associated with a user number. If one or the other comes up null then it will need to yell at me telling me that one was null. Iv been looking at the createCriteria information here http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html. It as a if NULL method. BUt it seems like that is to just search for values that is null. Is there a way i can implement that into my search?

```
if ((ilike('username', '%'+ username) || ilike('number', '%' + number) ) == (isNull('username') || isNull('number')){
        system.out.println("ONE OF THE VALUES IS NULL!")
```

I would like to think this would work like this. ^ But it doesn't

I am very new to all this. So constructive criticism is appreciated =D

Answer (score 0):

why are you submitting those strings as params?  Did you mean to do that?  And, you are sure this is an AND condition?

> It as a if NULL method. BUt it seems like that is to just search for values that is null. Is there a way i can implement that into my search?

Can you rephrase this?  (I don't understand what you are trying to do?)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was. Hibernate has a isNull() method. This method is something that looks like I could use but I think it just looks for values that are null. (But im not sure if I understand it fully). This search if for a populated table.

Pretty much. What I need to do is check this table that was populated from a database. The table needs to be searchable by Username and the users number. There are two search boxes that the person searching will have to put in the username and number. If for some reason one of those parameters show up null in the database then it needs to yell.

Comment: I think you need an 'or' condition, not 'and' in the criteria